# Form designs for displaying content in labels

Tags: css, forms, label

I see a *ton* of designs for forms that include form fields, but I can't find good examples of displaying labels in a form.

Does anyone have good layouts for forms that show information instead of gathering it? I've got a form that shows a user profile with several fields and I'd like to spread it across the horizontal area.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a nice effect by making your labels and data `display: inline-block` and giving your labels a fixed width and right-alignment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Mailing label</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .form div.row {
                margin-top: .25em;
            }

            .form span {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            .form span.label {
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-right: .25em;
                text-align: right;
                width: 10em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="row"><span class="label">Name:</span> <span class="value">Ben Blank</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span class="label">Address:</span> <span class="value">1024 Foo Bar Drive<br/>Silicon Valley, CA, 69105</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span class="label">E-Mail:</span> <span class="value">ben.blank@example.com</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span class="label">Phone:</span> <span class="value">(202) 555-1212</span></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an easy way, in css, to lay more than one label/field across the page horizontally?

Comment: Just set an explicit width on each element.  Inline-block will allow them to both take widths and to "flow" on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't talking about a form then.  Displaying user data can mimic the layout of a form, but if you don't have fields it's not a form.

Are you referring to the HTML label, or the .Net/Java UI concept of a label?  In HTML labels match up with input fields as a prompt ("First Name:", etc).  It sounds more like you're talking about the .Net label which is just a text placeholder.

Comment: I guess I'm talking about displaying data that has captions, like First Name, Last Name, Address, Email, in a pleasant way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this entirely depends on the nature of the data:

- If you're showing numbers, then fields would be smaller and you'll be able to show more data in one row.
- If you're showing long text, then it'll be difficult.
- It also depends on which pieces of data are more important and you want to show first.
- Finally, different users may need to see data in different ways.

Unfortunately, I believe there's no silver bullet for your problem... it's just a matter of common sense for your particular problem.